# Prevent RepositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit when Popup is Open When CloseUpKey.Key is pressed

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I use a `RepositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit`. its `CloseUpKey` property is set to `space`

```
result.CloseUpKey = new DevExpress.Utils.KeyShortcut(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Space);
```

I want to use this shortcut only for open popup and **not** for closing popup.

How can I achieve this?

UPDATE------------------------

First I create an `RepositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit` object

```
var result = new RepositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit();
result.CloseUpKey = new DevExpress.Utils.KeyShortcut(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Space);
result.KeyDown += repositoryItemLookUpEdit_KeyDown;
result.CloseUp += repositoryItemLookUpEdit_CloseUp;
result.QueryCloseUp += repositoryItemLookUpEdit_QueryCloseUp; 

private void repositoryItemLookUpEdit_QueryCloseUp(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var edit = sender as SearchLookUpEdit;
        KeyEventArgs k = new KeyEventArgs(edit.Properties.CloseUpKey.Key);
        AttachKeyPressEvent(k);
        if (k.KeyCode == edit.Properties.CloseUpKey.Key)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

And pass it to a grid column:

```
grdListView.Columns["yyy"].ColumnEdit = result
```

How can I achieve that with these `events`, without creating a  descendant `SearchLookUpEdit`

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

The problem is that CloseUp event (where you could get the necessary info about the closeup key) occurs after the QueryCloseUp event (where you could precent the closing up event). Also the KeyPress, KeyDown and KeyUp events seem also NOT to occur when the QueryCloseUp occurs, as a result they couldn't be overridden. So I tried this, I created a custom KeyEventHandler and triggered him during QueryCloseUp event in order to get the necessary info of what key was pressed and cancel the event if the close key event was the one. Here is my codeTry it to see if it suits you

```
       public partial class Form1 : Form
       {
         public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Here you can add your grid control as you have created
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID"); //use your own names and types
        gridControl1.DataSource = dt;

        var result = new RepositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit();
        result.CloseUpKey = new DevExpress.Utils.KeyShortcut(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Space);
        result.QueryCloseUp += new CancelEventHandler(repositoryItemLookUpEdit_QueryCloseUp);
        ((gridControl1.MainView as GridView).Columns["ID"] as GridColumn).ColumnEdit = result;
    }

    private static readonly object myQueryCloseUp = new object();

    public event KeyEventHandler MyQueryCloseUp
    {
        add { Events.AddHandler(myQueryCloseUp, value); }
        remove { Events.RemoveHandler(myQueryCloseUp, value); }
    }
    protected virtual void AttachKeyPressEvent(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        KeyEventHandler handler = (KeyEventHandler)Events[myQueryCloseUp];
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }
    //Here you add your own Handler implementation
    public void repositoryItemLookUpEdit_QueryCloseUp(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        KeyEventArgs k = new KeyEventArgs((sender as SearchLookUpEdit).Properties.CloseUpKey.Key);
        AttachKeyPressEvent(k);
        if (k.KeyCode == (sender as SearchLookUpEdit).Properties.CloseUpKey.Key)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank for answering, I have a problem inside QueryPopUp Event, knowing "when it is sent from CloseUp key".

Comment: when the event is triggered by pressing the key you have set as closeup key (that is space in your example), what kind of object is the sender of the event?

Comment: SearchLookUpEdit, problem is I dont have access to current keypressed value to compare it with CloseUpKey Property.

Comment: Check my updated answer. It worked at my test project

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'll check it asap.

Comment: Can I use this approach for "RepositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit" So I don't have to create a decendant SearchLookUpEdit? Problem is It doesn't have Events to use Addhandler and RemoveHandler.

Comment: How are you going to use the RepositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit? And what kind of cancellation of popup opening are you going to implement without a SearchLookUpEditobject and a QueryCloseUp event? Can you be more specific about your project?

Comment: Thanks for helping. I Updated my question And copied a bit of my code.

Comment: have you written code that implements your repositoryItemLookUpEdit_CloseUp event handler to show us?

Comment: I added the event. Problem is there is no Events in RepositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit to create the event handler u mentioned.

Comment: The Events Property is available due to System.Windows.Forms. Don't you use a Form? Where is the gridview going to be displayed?

Comment: If your c# code isn't too large please display the whole of it in order to understand how Customing Event Handlers can be implemented in your situation